# Creating key,value pair dynamically with angularjs and passing the same to java Map

Tags: java, angularjs

I have two empty text boxes in front end one for key and another for value one add button and a submit button.User can click on the add button to add one more pair of two text boxes each representing key and value respectively.

User is free to add any text as key and any text as value in the text boxes.
The submit button is to submit the final form.
I want to get these data in angularJS and further pass this to java Map through a post request.

To be specific a Map in java looks like this when converted to Json.

```
{"A":"something","B":"something","C":"something","D":"value"}
```

But I am not able to create such structure dynamically from front end using angularJS.

Comment: Why not? what is happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you need to map the key and value, I wont recommend array.
I think this is what you need:

```
$scope.map={};
//  Add header data
$scope.addToMap=function()
{
    $scope.map[$scope.key]=$scope.value;
    $scope.key="";    //clear the textbox
    $scope.value="";  //clear the textbox
};
```

execute `addToMap()` when your button is clicked. You can also have an `ng-repeat` with non-editable text boxes, and run the `ng-repeat` on `map`

Comment: This is the exact solution I was looking for.Thanks a lot Dushyant. I do not have the permission to vote this answer up. I wish if someone can vote this answer up for me.

Comment: @Amit, you can select it as the answer by clicking on the tick mark on the left side. You will eventually gain reputation and will be allowed to vote up. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try following code to create dynamic JSON object.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function MyCtrl($scope) {
 $scope.jsonObject = {};
  
  $scope.add = function(){
   $scope.jsonObject[$scope.key] = $scope.value;
  };
  
  $scope.submitForm = function(){
   console.log($scope.jsonObject);     
  }
}]);
```

```html
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <form>  
     Key: <input ng-model="key">
     Value: <input ng-model="value">
     <button ng-click="add()">ADD</button>
     <button ng-click="submitForm()">submit form</button>
   </form>
  
  <span>{{jsonObject}}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Sachin for the answer , this worked for me .It is quite similar to Dushyant's solution.

Answer (score 0):

try this
here is the working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/devidas7/Lvc0u55v/2993/)

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
 <input type="text" ng-model="item">
 </div>
  <button ng-click="addItem()">Add</button>
  </div>
```

Controller

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
 myApp.controller('MyCtrl',function($scope){
  $scope.items=['item1','item2','item3','item4','item5'];

  $scope.addItem = function(){
    $scope.items.push('');
  }
})
```

Comment: This is adding only one TextBox. I need two for each row and also both of them are supposed to be connected with key value pair relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Check this Plunker 
http://plnkr.co/edit/sgKYtxFGL1JyrVFMkQM4?p=info

```
$scope.name = {"A":"something","B":"something","C":"something","D":"value"};

$scope.example = $scope.name["A"];
```